# how to create popup menu in rails view file?

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I want to display some notification messages to user while either clicking on button or some events in webpage in rails.

how can I create interactive popup menu using jquery, bootstrap etc?

Thanks.

Comment: see https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr if this helps..?

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery plugin [tooltipster](http://iamceege.github.io/tooltipster/) offers such feature.
But there are a bunch out there: [jQuery Tooltip Plugins for Interactive Designs](http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2013/07/jquery-tooltip-plugin.html)
Though the [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html) also looks nice.